# Cannot open or copy file, but can move and delete

Tags: windows-10, encryption, file-permissions

(See below for a possibly decisive finding about encryption.)

A service I have written outputs a log file. I am trying to look at that log file.

Unfortunately, Windows refuses to let me see that log file - when I try to open it using Notepad, it says:

> You do not have permission to open this file. See the owner of the file or an administrator to obtain permission.

Notepad++ says it cannot open the file, either (even when running with admin priviledges). Likewise, trying to look at the file from within a web browser such as Firefox fails, as "Access to the file has been denied."

In fact, I cannot copy the file, either - not even from the command line in an admin console (also see below for my attempt at doing this with robocopy). Moving and deleting the file works fine, however.

The service *can* open the file. I can tell because whenever I launch the service (at which point it is expected to log some startup information), the file size increases

Now, according to the *Security* tab in the *Properties* dialog box for the file, my local user account has read and execute rights to the file.

I have checked the file permissions using `icactl.exe`. The (slightly redacted to remove personal info) output is as follows:

```
PREDEFINED\IIS_IUSRS:(I)(RX)
<machine>\<user>:(I)(RX)
PREDEFINED\Administrators:(I)(F)
NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
PREDEFINED\User:(I)(RX)
NT-AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
```

There are other log files (from other tools) in the same folder that I *can* open. Their `icacls` output looks exactly the same.

I have tried having the service write to a different file name. This doesn't change anything.

Lastly, I have checked with Process Explorer XP whether any process has a handle on the file (with the service not running), but it doesn't seem so.

**What can I do to access that log file?**

---

As suggested in the comments, I have tried to copy the file with robocopy, but to no avail:

```
C:\...\logs>robocopy C:\...\logs C:\...\logcopy svc.log /b

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robustes Dateikopieren für Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Gestartet: Montag, 21. Juni 2021 10:56:48
   Quelle : C:\...\logs\
     Ziel : C:\...\logcopy\

    Dateien : svc.log

  Optionen: /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /B /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           1    C:\...\logs\
            Neue Datei               700        svc.log
2021/06/21 10:56:48 FEHLER 2 (0x00000002) Dateiattribute werden geändert C:\...\logs\svc.log
Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           Insgesamt   KopiertÜbersprungenKeine Übereinstimmung    FEHLER    Extras
Verzeich.:         1         0         1         0         0         0
  Dateien:         1         0         0         0         1         0
    Bytes:       700         0         0         0       700         0
   Zeiten:   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Beendet: Montag, 21. Juni 2021 10:56:48

C:\...\logs
```

While that comes from a German Windows, in English, the message basically says:

> ERROR2 (0x00000002) File attributes modified
> The system cannot find the specified file.

---

**Update:** I may have found a trace of what is going on: The directory where the log files are saved has its "Encrypt content to protect data" checkbox checked.

If I have my service write its log files to another directory that is unencrypted, I can flawlessly open the log files.

Unfortunately, Windows says it cannot remove the "Encrypted" flag from the directory where I would actually like to get the log files in.

Comment: What service? Where is the log file stored? You wrote the service yourself, so theoretically you wrote the logging function. Please clarify your question if this is not the case

Comment: @music2myear: Indeed, I wrote the service myself, and I'm using [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) for logging. I am not sure what exactly is unclear. It is a service that can be registered and started with [`sc`](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html). And the log is file stored in a directory on my local hard disk. Please tell me what other information is required or what else I could check, if you have any idea.

Comment: And where did the error message come from> When a program opens a file it says what type of access it wants (read, write, read/write, or append) and what it will allow other programs to do with the file while it gas it open. So if you open a file with read access and allow other programs write access. Subsequent programs opening the file to write will succeed but programs opening the file to read will fail. There was a change in notepad. It used to open files read only then close the file. If you saved it tried to open the file with write access, write it then close it.

Comment: For speed reasons Notepad changed to memory mapped files so always tries to open with write access. Use use a different text editor.

Comment: @user1292580: I edited in some information about the editors used. Note, though, that my attempts at opening the file happen at a time when the service is stopped again. Also, as described in the question, no process is having a handle on the file. (With that said, in my experience NLog does not lock files like that; in fact, one of the purposes of logging is often to being able to see changes to the logfile as they happen, while the application that writes the log is running.) Also, I'm not sure this can explain why I cannot copy the file.

Comment: 1) If you run Notepad++ as Administrator, can you open the file? 2) Is the file located in a subdirectory of the website such that you could assign useful inherited permissions on child objects of that subdirectory?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: 1) No, even when running Notepad++ with admin priviledges, it says I do not have the required permissions to open the file. 2) The log file is not among the directory trees published as a website. What permissions do you imagine I could inherit from where exactly; could you give an example, please?

Comment: Have you trying copying it with ```robocopy /b``` to see if you can copy using backup powers?

Try running ```procmon``` and see what happens when you try to open it. 

You can also try to start a ```cmd``` as [SYSTEM](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-to-launch-a-windows-command-prompt-as-system-in-windows-10/)  and open it with notepad.

Comment: @LuizAngelo: I cannot copy the file with Robocopy: Robocopy displays the name and the size of the file, then says: "ERROR 2 (0x00000002) File attributes are changed <full file path> The system cannot find the specified file."

Comment: @LuizAngelo: Using Process Monitor, I can see that Notepad attempts to open the file with Read access, but that access gets denied. I also see that some attempts by Explorer.exe to access the file result in the states "INVALID PARAMETER" or "NAME INVALID". I am not quite sure what to make of that or what else to look for in ProcMon's output.

Comment: That's an odd message. Did you try with ```/b```? With backup privileges?

Comment: Can you paste the full ```robocopy``` comand in the question and then the output you are getting?

"NAME INVALID". Maybe the path is too long? Maybe there's some invalid character in the file's path or name?

Comment: @LuizAngelo: Yes, I was using the `/b` switch to enable backup priviledges for Robocopy. I have added the full (anonymized) output to the question. No, the path is not too long - other files with longer names in the same directory that I can open can be copied flawlessly. Hence, there are also no invalid characters in the path, or this would be an issue for the other files, as well. I have had the service write to various filenames, but the simplest one, as shown above, is `svc.log` - again, no invalid characters.